# Profesionally Printed Labels?

Tags: beer, bottles, labels, printing

A friend has offered to design labels for a few of my favourite beers. I just got the first one, and I love it. The only problem is some of the design elements don't show up very well when printed on a home laser or inkjet printer.

But I love it so much, I'm thinking about getting several hundred printed by a professional offset printing company that can reproduce the fine details she put into the design. Does anyone have any suggestions for offset printing companies that handle beer labels? Enough with marking the caps of the beers and trying to remember what each letter stands for. :)

Comment: Make sure you spell-check your labels. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I had some printed at bottleyourbrand.com, they turned out pretty well.  I would suggest ordering a few and judging the quality before you order several hundred.  I'm sure that there are other label printing companies, I just haven't used them before.

Answer (score 2):

I would also suggest looking at [Presto Labels](http://www.prestolabels.com/); their pricing is reasonable, and easily discoverable. You will find (unfortunately) that small runs of 100 labels are annoyingly expensive. On the other hand, if you have a recipe that you really like & do frequently, getting 500 labels made up might be worth it. I'd be tempted to have a semi-custom label done with my name & some artwork on it + a place to write in the recipe name & date with a sharpie.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this place today: http://www.grogtag.com They make re-stickable vinyl labels, and have a template for you to upload your own label for them to print. Prices looked pretty good, too: under $1 per label, and cheaper if you buy more.

Answer (score 1):

I would bring a thumb-drive to Office Max, Office Depot or one of those places before I spent a lot of money on "offset" printing.  Those office stores have really good color printers and are really inexpensive.  They will print on various label stock they have, or you can bring your own label stock (even cheaper).  I made a JPG with 6 labels per page, so labeled a 5 gallon batch of 12oz bottles for just a few bucks.  Also, they do it while you wait, which is a big plus.

[image: www.beerlabelizer.com]

And in the spirit of saving money, you can even make your labels online for free (or donate) and download the JPG file at [www.beerlabelizer.com](http://www.beerlabelizer.com).

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't very helpful but you could try looking up the printing company who print the bottle labels/caps for "Wychwood brewery" their bottle caps are always intricately designed with teeny details.